# A better way to get an array of strings separating a string on N character incrementally

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I am trying to find a better way to get an array of strings based on a string by separating on a special character, in my case the `/` character.

So given the following input:

```
"/bob/ross/is/awesome/squirrels"
```

I would like to end up with:

```
[
    "/bob/ross/is/awesome/squirrels", 
    "/bob/ross/is/awesome", 
    "/bob/ross/is", 
    "/bob/ross", 
    "/bob"
]
```

I must admit that despite my years of experience I am stuck as to how to approach this eloquently and succinctly.

Here is my current code:

```
getWords = function( string ){

    // Get an array of all words in the provided string separating on "/"
    let words = string.split("/");

    // Filter out empty strings from leading/trailing "/" characters
    words = words.filter( function(a){return a !== ""} );

    // Create an array to store results in
    let results = [];

    // Create an iteration for each word in the array
    for (var i=0, j=words.length; i<j; i++){

        // Create a string to concatenate to
        let result = "";

        // Loop over each word in the array minus the current iteration of "i"
        for (var k=0, l=words.length - i; k<l; k++){

            // Contatenate using the special character plus the current word
            result += "/" + words[k];
        }

        // Push the resulting string to the results array
        results.push(result);
    }

    // Return the results array
    return results;
}
```

And a code snippet for you to check what's going on:

```js
getWords = function( string ){

    // Get an array of all words in the provided string separating on "/"
    let words = string.split("/");

    // Filter out empty strings from leading/trailing "/" characters
    words = words.filter( function(a){return a !== ""} );

    // Create an array to store results in
    let results = [];

    // Create an iteration for each word in the array
    for (var i=0, j=words.length; i<j; i++){

        // Create a string to concatenate to
        let result = "";

        // Loop over each word in the array minus the current iteration of "i"
        for (var k=0, l=words.length - i; k<l; k++){

            // Contatenate using the special character plus the current word
            result += "/" + words[k];
        }

        // Push the resulting string to the results array
        results.push(result);
    }
    
    // Set the results to display
    resultsDisplay.innerHTML = results.toString().replace(/,/g, " -- ");

    // Return the results array
    return results;
}

input = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0];
resultsDisplay = document.getElementsByClassName("results")[0];
input.addEventListener("input", function(){
getWords(input.value)
});
getWords(input.value);
```

```html
<input value="bob/ross/is/awesome/squirrels" />
<p class="results"></p>
```

Comment: You could use `.join("/")` to glue the array back into a string, add that string to the list, and then use `.pop()` to remove the last element of the split array. Keep doing that until there are no elements in it.

Comment: `results.push("/"+words.slice(0, i).join("/"))`?

Comment: This question could be suitable for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help), as long as (a) your code works as intended, (b) your code is real code, rather than example code, and (c) your code is included in the body of the question. If you wish for a peer review to improve all aspects of your code, please post it on Code Review.

Comment: Will post future posts like this in Code Review.  Leaving this one here so the top answer retains his points.

Comment: I honestly wouldn't advise recursion in JS, however since you have asked for it, i have provided a recursive answer down below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may do as follows;

```js
var str = "/bob/ross/is/awesome/squirrels",
    res = s => s.length ? [s].concat(res(s.match(/.*(?=\/.+$)/)[0])) : [];
console.log(res(str));
```

**Explanation:** So in the above snippet we have a `String.match()` portion  with regexp which matches the text before the last "/" character. This matched text will be the next string we will feed to the `res` function call recursively from within itself like `res(s.match(/.*(?=\/.+$)/)[0])`.
So the `res function` is a recursive one with a terminating condition being an argument `s` of 0 length string in which case it returns an empty array. However if `s` is not empty then it's first placed in an array and then the array is concatenated with the result of a recursive call and returned.

Comment: This is awesome. Could you edit with a description of what exactly is happening in this code snippet?

Answer (score 1):

This would do it:

```
var path = "/bob/ross/is/awesome/squirrels";
var arr = path.split('/').filter(val => val);
var res = arr.map((val, idx) => '/'+arr.slice(0,idx+1).join('/'))
console.log(res)
```

Comment: where is the recursion..?

Comment: @Redu What recursion?

Comment: @Redu - Why would it need recursion?

Comment: Normally it does not and it shouldn't but the OP requested recursion. That's how I understood.

Comment: I can't see where he requests recursion (and why would he?).Your comments look petulant, it's not the way SO should be.

Comment: @melpomene The mention of recursion was in the topic before it's been edited into "incrementally" by yourself.

Comment: @dashton Don't be fooled. The topic mentioned "recursion" (check edits) and this melpomene guy has edited it into "incrementally" just to ask "what recursion..?" I agree it's not the way SO should be... I haven't seen such a lame act in SO before.

Comment: @Redu No, I first asked "what recursion" because I didn't see recursion mentioned anywhere in OP's question. Later I realized it was in the subject line, but it doesn't make much sense there: The problem as described by OP isn't recursive and even his original code just uses `for` loops. That's when I edited it. I don't think OP was specifically asking for a recursive solution, just more elegant code than what he had.

Comment: @dashton well since you have explained, sorry for the lame part above, however even unintentionally, your edit renders my "where is the recursion?" comment under some of the answers look reasonless. On the other hand I have to agree that recursion might not be an ideal way of solving this problem especially in JS, yet that's what OP had requested.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach:

```js
let str = "/bob/ross/is/awesome/squirrels";
let re = /\/+[^\/]+/g;
let result = [];
while (re.exec(str)) {
    result.push(str.substr(0, re.lastIndex));
}
result.reverse();
console.log(result);
```

Comment: where is the recursion..?

Comment: @Redu What recursion?